# Local web page not loading correctly

Tags: firefox, fedora, html, css

I'm learning to code websites. I decided to start using fedora. All is well until i find that my CSS file isnt loading correctly. The same configuratiin worked in chrome for windows but not FF for linux.

I have a folder `/home/cromwell/projects` inside of which I have an `index.html` and a `styles.css` (as well as associated resources)

I reference the css file with `href="styles.css"'`... I also tried `./styles.css` and `file:///C:/home/cromwell....`

The `./` method resolves and shows my css file when i click the link in "view page source". But it does not populate to the DOM when the page loads.

The css file is nothing more than a normalize. And the html only references the stylesheet. No content.

Why won't my css load? This setup was working in Windows... Do I need to set up an apache server? Is there a syntax to the path im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong tag... Had a meta when i needed a link... Im sorry and thank you for your excellent answers

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your files to a public accessible folder. That is the only time you can load the CSS file. As a safe trick, put your css file on the same folder of your html file then use this linking code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
```

You won't be able to use `file:///C:/home/cromwell....` since Fedora have no concept of drive letters as default, it sees everything as folders unless you mount a drive and give it a drive letter.

It is also a big no to include a drive letter to your html links since it will search the file local to the visitors hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the only problem here is that there is no `C:`. The idea of giving drives (or partitions, or network shares) letters is a peculiar idiosyncrasy of DOS carried over to Windows. In Linux, there is one unified tree, and it starts at `/`. Other partitions/drives/shares may be mounted into that tree, but from a user perspective, you don't need to care about. So, you just need to reference your files at `file:///home/cromwell/...`

Comment: A apologize. The problem was a standard silly mistake. I was using a meta tag when i should have had a link tag... Which is not helpful for anyone else. Thank you for trying and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You're welcome. And in any case this is still also true.